# Visual Studio Installer Package not Building

Tags: visual-studio, installation, building

i am trying to build an installer for a windows service i have created and when i go to build the module i am getting the following message..

========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

but there is no information about what actually failed.

For some reason the installer is not building right. does anyone know how i can get more information?

Comment: not sure whether to laugh. tried that before posting.

Answer (score 0):

It's very odd that it would fail with no error messages.  Can you try to do a build clean followed by an explicit rebuild all.

Please make sure to check

- Output Window
- Task List (make sure it's pointing to build error and not todo information)

Comment: the weird thing is that it does produce an msi

Answer (score 0):

Seems kinda silly but are you sure you don't have your build output set to Quiet?:

Tools->Options-->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run.

Check the 'MSBuild project build output verbosity' that it's not set to Quiet.  Usually Minimal will give you enough info to go on, although you could try a higher setting.

Comment: have looked and found nothing to indicate a failed build. one thing i did find is that if i create a new solution and slowly build back the old one, the point at which the new installer fails is when i ad a linq dataclass. are there any known issues with linq and a vs installer?